# Implementing JSR-303 validation with crnk JSON API

Tags: spring-boot, crnk

I am fairly familiar with the JSR-303's `@Valid` annotation and have used it a couple of times in my `@Controller` classes. For example:

```
    @PostMapping("/users")
    ResponseEntity<String> addUser(@Valid @RequestBody User user) {
        // persisting the user
        return ResponseEntity.ok("User is valid");
    }
```

Where `User` object is a typical class with annotations like `@NotBlank` or `@NotNull` on the fields.

However, I am trying to build a REST API based on JSON API using the crnk library and am trying to do the same validation, example:

```
    @Override
    public Subscription save(@Valid Subscription subscription) {
    // code goes here
    }
```

Unfortunately the validation doesn't work and I have tried both `@Valid` and `@Validation`.

Can anyone kindly show what is wrong with this code?

Thanks

Comment: "doesn't work" why not? what happens? what would be instead of `// code goes here`?

Comment: `//code goes here` is the typical service call and the call to the repository/DB. What I meant by doesn't work is that the validation doesn't check if the inputs are valid or not.